# can?(:update) returning false, but cancan not restricting edit / updates on resource with inherited_resources gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan, inherited-resources

I'm using cancan with inherited resources and I'm encountering a strange issue (possibly bug?) where I defined a permission for an edit permission for a user and suddenly they are authorized to access the /edit action despite the ability returning false. So here's the behavior I'm experiencing.

```
class VenuesController < ApplicationController
  inherit_resources
  authorize_resource
end
```

Without an ability defined, my non-admin user is redirected from /venues/1/edit to the homepage. However, once I define an :update ability, I am not redirected whether the ability returns true or false. Here is the ability I want to define:

## ability.rb

```
can :update, Venue do |venue|
  venue.admin_ids.map{|a| a.to_s}.include? user.id.to_s
end
```

This returns the correct value as I can see with my test as well as with a sanity check inside my view:

## venues/edit.html.haml

```
= can? :update, @venue
#returns false
```

So, if I'm inside the edit action and my view says "I cannot update", shouldn't cancan be redirecting me from this page? As a double-sanity-check, I tried

```
can :update, Venue do |venue|
  false
end
```

and still no luck... I just find it strange that without any ability definition whatsoever, I'm redirected, but when I define an ability that returns false, I'm not redirected despite the view layer appropriately telling me I cannot edit. Any ideas? Is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong?

Furthermore, not only am I able to see the edit action, but actually make put requests to the resource and the resource saves.

Comment: you are defining the :update action, but checking it on the edit action. sure that you are looking at the right place?

Comment: I thought cancan restricts update and edit with the "update" ability.

Comment: Anyhow even if I explicitly tell cancan that my user has no permissions to :edit, I still don't get redirected at all